# Finding a cell with a specific string in it and replacing the cell 2 columns to the right with a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

As the title states, I need to find all cells in a worksheet with a specific string in them and replace the cell 2 columns to the right with a specific value

Edit: this is what I have so far but no idea where to go from here

```
Sub t()
Dim searchCell As Range  
Dim replaceCell As Range
With Sheets("Chainwire")
    Set searchCell = .Cells.Find(what:="UFFT50")
    Set replaceCell = searchCell.Offset(0, 2)
End With
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: If the data isn't massive, simplest approach would be a `For Each` loop over the `.Cells`, coupled with either `Instr` or `Like` (depending if case sensitively matters) to do the comparison. For writing to a cell 2 column to the right, use `.Offset(0, 2) =`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there - it's not very readable in a comment

Comment: Now please include the error you are getting, and on what line. Did your `.Find` succeed? if not, then `searchCell` is going to equal `Nothing`, and you cannot use it on the next line. Also, it seems you are not even trying to do anything with `replaceCell`.

Comment: @braX When I run this code nothing happens, no errors are thrown and no results or changes happen in the worksheet

Comment: Right, because you are not doing anything with `replaceCell` - are you planning on setting its value?

Comment: This is my issue, I'm not sure of the code required to change every cell where it finds "UFFT50". I understand that this code finds every cell that has UFFT50 in it and then I would like to change the cell 2 columns to the right (Offset(0, 2)) to 8.00

Comment: Plenty of examples here on SO, and in the wider web, of how to approach this.  Important to point out SO isn't a free coding service. So that means you do need to do some searching, thinking and application. See [help] on ways to write a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub ReplaceItems()
    Dim col, c, dest As Range
    
    Set col = FindAll(Sheets("Chainwire").UsedRange, "UFFT50") 'get all matches
    
    'loop matches and replace value 2 cells over
    For Each c In col
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "a specific value"
    Next
End Sub


'search a Range for `val` and return all matches as a Collection
'   of cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String
    'adjust Find() arguments to suit your need...
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address() 'remember first cell found

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do 'exit if we looped back to the first hit
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```